# angular js ng-repeat optgroup by Frequent and Allcountries with id's as key and name as value

Tags: angularjs

```
  "data": {
    "Frequent": {
      "56": "Germany",
      "67": "Spain",
      "74": "France",
      "76": "United Kingdom",
      "230": "United States of America",
      "": "Select Country"
    },
    "AllCountries": {
      "1": "Andorra",
      "2": "United Arab Emirates",
      "3": "Afghanistan",
      "4": "Antigua and Barbuda",
      "5": "Anguilla",
      "6": "Albania"
   }
}
```

Comment: <select  class="form-control" ng-model="editProfCtrl.result.country" >        
       <optgroup ng-repeat="(groupName, items) in editProfCtrl.countriesss" label="<%groupName%>">
         <option ng-cloak class="ng-cloak"  ng-repeat="items" value="<%items%>"><% items %></option>
       </optgroup>
      </select>